# How to replace all spaces followed by question mark with comma in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here i have 3 scenarios like ( ?),(? )and (?)

var data = "Hello?Welcome ?to the? world"

This is JavaScript so I have tried like below and meeting one scenario but not all.

data.replace(/[ ?]+/g, ',');

Expected result:
Hello,welcome,to the,world

Comment: No? I copied and pasted your two lines into my browser console and got exactly what you show as the expected result.

Comment: *Replace all spaces followed by question mark with comma* : `data.replace(/( +\?)/g, ',');`

Comment: You can use a capture group with the pipe symbol to separate multiple options |  data.replace(/( \?|\? |\?)/g, ",") . Remember ? is a reserved regex operator and should be escaped \?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let data = "Hello?Welcome ?to the? world";
    data = data.replace(/\s?\?\s?/g, ',');
    console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your regex is wrong:

```
/[ ?]+/g
```

This means match one or more of any characters: "space or ?". Meaning, that just a single space may be replaced.

You should change the regex to:

```
/( ?)|(? )|(?)/g
```

meaning "Match either of these three patterns"